# @MicronautTest - limit what is instantiated

Tags: java, micronaut

Whenever I used `@MicronautTest` in my project, the whole application is started as a whole and because certain things need to be done at startup by services, they are executed also.
I don't need the whole Singleton shebang when I'm testing a simple controller.

My question is how do I limit which controllers and singletons are loaded when testing Micronaut?

I have a small demo example which shows the problem

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
        <release.version>11</release.version>
        <micronaut.version>2.5.1</micronaut.version>
        <exec.mainClass>com.example.Application</exec.mainClass>
        <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
                    <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

                    <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.example</arg>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=micronaut-test</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.java

```
package com.example;

import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

A simple service that throws whenever it is instantiated to indicate the problem

```
@Singleton
public class SingletonService {

    @EventListener
    public void init(ApplicationStartupEvent event) {
        throw new RuntimeException("I was initialized");
    }
}
```

A simple controller

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Get
    public Simple findAll() {
        return new Simple("ATest");
    }

    public static class Simple {
        private final String test;

        public Simple(String test) {
            this.test = test;
        }

        public String getTest() {
            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

And a straightforward test

```
@MicronautTest
class TestControllerTest {
    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    RxHttpClient rxHttpClient;

    @Test
    void controller() {
        HttpResponse<ByteBuffer> byteBufferHttpResponse = rxHttpClient.exchange("/").blockingFirst();
        assert byteBufferHttpResponse.getStatus().getCode() == 200;
    }
}
```

The test results are

```
[INFO] Running com.example.controller.TestControllerTest
11:01:52.804 [main] INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [test]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.232 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.controller.TestControllerTest
[ERROR] com.example.controller.TestControllerTest  Time elapsed: 7.229 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: I was initialized
```

How do I prevent the test from starting that SingletonService? Stubbing is an option but keep in mind that this is a simple demo illustrating the issue for a bigger project. Is there no other straightforward way?
According to the [docs](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/) of @MicronautTest, it shouldn't be scanning the classpath but it clearly is?

Here are some other configurations I've already attempted without any success:

Adding a ApplicationBuilder that disables eagerInit

```
@MicronautTest(application = TestControllerTest.TestApplication.class)
class TestControllerTest {
    public static class TestApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Micronaut.build(args)
                    .eagerInitAnnotated(null)
                    .eagerInitSingletons(false)
                    .mainClass(TestApplication.class);
        }
    }
    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    RxHttpClient rxHttpClient;

    @Test
    void controller() {
        HttpResponse<ByteBuffer> byteBufferHttpResponse = rxHttpClient.exchange("/").blockingFirst();
        assert byteBufferHttpResponse.getStatus().getCode() == 200;
    }
}
```

Passing along a contextbuilder

```
@MicronautTest(contextBuilder = TestControllerTest.TestContextBuilder.class)
class TestControllerTest {

    public static class TestContextBuilder extends DefaultApplicationContextBuilder {
        public TestContextBuilder() {
            eagerInitSingletons(false);
            eagerInitAnnotated(null);
            eagerInitConfiguration(false);
        }
    }

    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    RxHttpClient rxHttpClient;

    @Test
    void controller() {
        HttpResponse<ByteBuffer> byteBufferHttpResponse = rxHttpClient.exchange("/").blockingFirst();
        assert byteBufferHttpResponse.getStatus().getCode() == 200;
    }
}
```

Which all yield the same response.

Hopefully someone knows how to limit the scope of bean instantation with the @MicronautTest or I'll most likely switch back to Spring boot

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how do I limit which controllers and singletons are
> loaded when testing Micronaut?

At least there is the `@Requires` annotation that allows doing flexible configuration if a bean should be loaded within the current environment.

For example, in your case it should be something like:

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requires;

@Singleton
@Requires(notEnv = {Environment.TEST})
public class SingletonService {

    @EventListener
    public void init(ApplicationStartupEvent event) {
        throw new RuntimeException("I was initialized");
    }
}
```

As a result, the exception from the service is not thrown.

However, I don't really know the purpose why you need to exclude the service. And it could be that other approaches might be more convenient.

For example, see `Mocking Collaborators` section from the micronaut test documentation: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/

Comment: Let's say I have a singleton that check if a website is up every minute. How does that one tie in to a controller which just print a hello?
This is why I'd like to exclude certain singletons. Those that don't have anything to do with the thing I'm trying to test shouldn't be running in their production form